# How exactly do solution configurations work in Visual Studio?

Tags: configuration, visual-studio-2017

When in a .sln file, you have the default choices of 'Debug' and 'Release'. From what I understand these are 'build settings' of some sort differ depending on the kind of build you are doing?

I recently played around with creating my own settings, and found (much to my surprise) that creating the configuration name didn't seem to create the symbol as recognized by:

```
#if MY_SHINY_NEW_SYMBOL  
    Console.WriteLine("TESTING MY SYMBOL");  
#endif
```

And on the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if) I can see that there is code to allow you to actually define the symbol (presumably separately from just creating one in the Configuration Manager):

```
#define DEBUG  
// ...
```

How do these symbols work and where are they configured?

i'm asking because I accidentally created a symbol called 'local'. I deleted it and then created a symbol called 'Local'. And I'm getting compile errors because it seems that the 'local' symbol still exists and I can't overwrite it with a symbol using a different case.

I haven't configured the symbol at all, I'm using the variable `$(ConfigurationName)` in my pre-build event commands.

I'm actually fairly sure this is a Visual Studio bug, since I would think that deleting a configuration, recreated the same configuration with different case, would NOT result in the original configuration reappearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build configurations become MSBuild variables that can be referenced in MSBuild properties in the `csproj` file (remember that .Net project files are actually MSBuild scripts).

In particular, the Visual Studio Project Properties window will let you set most properties on a per-configuration basis (by wrapping it in a conditional block).

In particular, the `DEBUG` symbol is set like this (you'll see this in every `csproj` file, but a bit less simple):

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
    ...
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    ...
</PropertyGroup>
```

You could also replace this and set a symbol for the configuration directly:

```
<DefineConstants>$(Configuration)</DefineConstants>
```

However, VS is likely to change that if it saves your project file.

Comment: Thank you - I didn't know that VS is effectively a UI for creating an MSBuild script! (Is that a correct way of phrasing this?)

Comment: @ZachSmith: Yes (well, that part of VS).